# How to write mp3 frames from PCM data (C/C++)?

Tags: c++, c, mp3, frames, pcm

How to write mp3 frames (not full mp3 files with ID3 etc) from PCM data?

I have something like PCM data (for ex 100mb) I want to create an array of mp3 frames from that data. How to perform such operation? (for ex with lame or any other opensource encoder)

What do I need:

- Open Source Libs for encoding.
- Tutorials and blog articles on How to do it, about etc.

Comment: LAME is LGPL. Why don't you want to use it? Or your program will not be opensource?

Comment: @Piligrim Anyway he can use LAME even in a closed-sourced program, that's the point of LPGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use LAME. It has a [-t command line switch](http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/*checkout*/lame/lame/doc/html/switchs.html#t) that turns off the INFO header in the output (otherwise present in frame 0). If that still leaves too much bookkeeping data, you should be able to write a separate tool to strip that away.

Comment: addition, look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/mpegaudioinfo.aspx for information about the mpeg (header) format. With that information it should be possible to process the resulting mp3 file.

Answer (score 1):

You are already on the right track: use LAME external executable, or any other shell-invoked encoder.

To build MP frames, were your layer of interest is 3, is not easy to do from scratch. There are compression steps, Fast-fourier transforms followed by quantization, which are of complex and tediously long explanation. The amount of work required for a developer to build it from scratch is very big.
There are programmatic C and C++ MP encoding libs, but you will be either asked for fees, be left with very limited support, or have very limited interfacing options.

Go LAME, study their [wiki](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Lame).